# Definir y obtener el Locale actual de Configuration en Android N?

Tags: java, android

Como se puede asignar un `locale` y obtener el `locale` actual en Android N?

```
Configuration conf = getResources().getConfiguration();
conf.locale = new Locale("es") // Deprecated
String language = conf.locale.getDisplayName() //Deprecated
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En este [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38267213/android-how-to-get-the-current-locale-api-24) he encontrado la solución.

```
Locale locale;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    locale = context.getResources().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0);
} else {
    locale = context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
}
```

A partir de Android N se debe realizar así:

```
Configuration conf = getResources().getConfiguration();
conf.setLocale = new Locale("es") // VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1+ 
String language = conf.getLocales().get(0).toString() // VERSION_CODES.N+
```

Answer (score 1):

Otra alternativa a lo que estás poniendo sería lo siguiente:

Para obtener el locale actual:

```
Configuration config = context.getResources().getConfiguration();

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
     locale = getSystemLocale(config);
} else {
     locale = getSystemLocaleLegacy(config);
}
```

y para actualizar el locale:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("es");
Locale.setDefault(locale);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
     setSystemLocale(config, locale);
} else {
     setSystemLocaleLegacy(config, locale);
}
```